# How to redirect user after logged in in WordPress within a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

```
public function afterLoginRedirect()
{
    wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/pages/main.php' );
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', [ $this, 'afterLoginRedirect' ] );
```

I am using login redirect hook within my own plugin. But when a user login using WordPress email/username and password then it can't redirect.

Comment: Check this doc: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Comment: yes I checked. but it can't run on my plugin

Comment: remove wp_redirect and use return url

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a filter and you forgot to return it.You always have to return something while applying a filter. You will have to add something like this into your plugin to redirect your users after login happens.

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to) {
      $redirect_to = 'http://yourwebsitename.com/yourpage';
        return $redirect_to;

}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```